# SELECT * FROM multiple tables, group by ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

**purpose**: I have been tasked with exporting a complex dataset from a PHP counseling appointment webapp, and convert it into an excel file containing student data sorted by their `STUDENT_ID`.

I have 3 MySQL tables containing data. They all have a `STUDENT_ID` field.

I need to make a query which retrieves all the data from the 4 tables, grouping into a single row based on `STUDENT_ID`.

Some of the tables contain multiple entries for the same `STUDENT_ID`. If possible I'd like these multiple entries combined into a single row (so that each unique `STUDENT_ID` is on one line).

This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work how I expect it to.

```
SELECT *
from ssp_student t1
INNER JOIN ssp_student_quarterly t2 
ON t1.STUDENT_ID = t2.STUDENT_ID 
INNER JOIN ssp_weekly_progress t3 
ON t2.STUDENT_ID = t3.STUDENT_ID
GROUP BY t1.STUDENT_ID
```

Table Schema:

```
Table 1: 
| STUDENT_ID | PEER_COACH_ID | ACTIVE | COHORT | WEEKLY_MEETING_TIME | FYE_ID | RC | AGREEMENT_SIGNED | RELEASE_SIGNED | NOTES | FACULTY_ADVISOR |

Table 2:
| STUDENT_ID | QUARTER | COUNSELLING_OFFICE | WRITING_CENTER | CASE_MANAGEMENT | SSP_SOCIAL_EVENTS | SSP_SUCCESS_SEMINAR | HOME_SUPPORT | ACCOMODATION_USED | DISCOVERY_PATHWAYS | PEER_COACHING |

Table 3:
| STUDENT_ID | QUARTER | WEEK | EMAIL_INTERACTION | PHONE_INTERACTION | TEXT_INTERACTION | INPERSON_INTERACTION | SOCIAL_INTERACTION | NUMBER_OF_SOCIAL_INTERACTIONS | CASE_MANAGEMENT_INTERACTIONS | NUMBER_OF_CASE_mANAGEMENT_INTERACTIONS | SUCCESS_SEMINAR_INTERACTION | NUMBER_OF_SUCCESS_SEMINAR_INTERACTIONS | OTHER_INTERACTION | THEMES | SURVEY_ID | NOTES |
```

---

**what I need:** I want 1 row for each `STUDENT_ID`, which contains columns for all the data associated with that `STUDENT_ID` in tables 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Please tell us what you expect and why it doesn't work like you expect. Your database schema would also help us.

Comment: There are two problems here: (1) If some tables have multiple rows with that student_id - you will get useless result (only one of the relevant rows) and (2) If some of the tables don't contain anything about that student - you will not get that at all. For the second reason - consider `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @DamienBlack I've edited the OP with DB schema and more info.

Comment: Please make sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use SELECT * and you say that some of the tables contain more than one row for the same student, you will never get only one row. Try to select the fields related to the student id that you want to display.

If any of the fields that you want to display is one of the multiple-entry, then it will not work, it will display one row per entry.

Comment: Actually, that's not right. He groups the result by student id in the end, so there will be exactly one row per student. But for tables that had more than one row in the original join - only one (unpredictable which) row will be used in the result.

Comment: I mean, *you will never get only one row* is not true... the rest is ;)

Comment: yes, you're right, my explication was terrible actually hehe I meant that if needed to display one of the columns with more than one entry, they would be displayed in 2 columns (unless he uses an aggregate function, etc.) ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to concatenate the data for each row into one field, your `SELECT` statement you could do something like the following:

```
SELECT t1.STUDENT_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.Field1 SEPARATOR ', ') AS t2Field1Concat,
                      GROUP_CONCAT(t2.Field2 SEPARATOR ', ') AS t2Field2Concat,
                      GROUP_CONCAT(t3.Field1 SEPARATOR ', ') AS t3Field1Concat,
                      GROUP_CONCAT(t3.Field2 SEPARATOR ', ') AS t3Field2Concat
```

In the above example you would have to do this for each field other than `t1.STUDENT_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be after 4 separate groups of data that have virtually nothing in common other than the student ID. You should perform a single query for each and then combine the data into a relevant format in PHP.

Joining all 4 tables together like this is going to end up with a potentially *MASSIVE* result set full of duplicate data.

Comment: Im open to all ways to approach this. you're correct the data is very disparate. What is your recommendation for querying each individually and combining them? Just select * by STUDENT_ID in each table one after another? The end result must be formatted for export as CSV.

Comment: Well then it's dependent on the format requirements of the CSV data, as well as the particulars of the source data. Can it only be a single CSV file with one row per student? Do all these tables have a 1:1 relationship? If it's yes to both, or yes to the second question, then a single select would be your best option. If you've got 1:n or m:n relationships between any of these tables then you should probably be exporting data to separate CSV files using multiple queries.